# Class include not letting variables work inside templates

Tags: php, class, include, undefined

I have a PHP class that makes it just easier to insert templates that I've created...

ie

```
...
 /*Get Templates*/
 public function template($file){
       if(isset($file) && file_exists($file.".php")){
          $controller = $this;
          include $file.".php";
       }else{
          echo "";
       }
    }
```

Which is located in a directory outside `public_html` as so

`kms/php_includes/kms.php`

But if I am using it in my index page

`public_html/index.php`

None of the variables i set in index work inside the templates?

Example

index.php

```
$user = "Mr.EasyBB";
$controller->template("../kms/site/header");//$controller is the class variable
```

header.php

```
echo $user; //this doesn't work
$controller->template("../kms/site/svg/smile"); //this still works
```

But in `kms/site/header.php`

I get the `undefined variable user` directed to the header php file. Is this due to the origin of the template being outside of `public_html` or am I doing something silly here and not realizing it.

Seems to me the problem is the location of the files being in complete different directories so my trivial practice was to add a set and get.

```
 ...
 private $variables = array();

 public function get($prop){
    if($this->variables[$prop]){
       return $this->variables[$prop];
    }
 }
 public function set($prop=null,$val=null){
   if($prop !== null && $val !== null){
       $this->variables[$prop] = $val;
     }
 }

 /*Get Templates*/
 public function template($file){
       if(isset($file) && file_exists($file.".php")){
          $controller = $this;
          foreach($this->variables as $var->$val){
             //i need to assign explicitly the $var name here hence why I used double dollar signs. But it's not working either.
             $$var = $val;
          }
          include $file.".php";
       }else{
          echo "";
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two files cannot communicate with each other because they are given two different scopes; they are included in two separate calls to `template()`

Try setting `$controller->user` within `index.php` and reusing it in `header.php`.

```
// controller
function template() {
    $this->user = 'Foo';
    include 'header.php'; // tells php to use header.php as if
                          // it were just more code for this function
}

// header.php
echo $this->user; // Foo
```

You can also stash your variables in an array and extract them before including the header.

```
// controller
function template() {
    $this->templateVars['user'] = 'Foo';
    extract($this->templateVars);
    echo $user; // Foo
    include 'header.php';
}

// header.php
echo $user; // Foo
```

I would advise against that, however, you can forget where variables come from easily if your templates are large and create their own. But if you need to, you can make the extracted variable names all uppercase to indicate that they came from the controller.

```
$this->templateVars['USER'] = 'Foo'; // etc
```

Comment: `$controller` is `$controller = new KMS();` so why would `$controller->user` work? I haven't tried it I'm just curious. And there is one call which is from the index page to my template header. I've had them working once before but, the templates, the class, and where I was doing this which was an admin page were all in the same parent directory. I think it may have to do with the locations of each file.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was suggesting with my answer. :) The problem wasn't that the files were in separate directories, the problem is that the variables you create have different scopes and can't see each other. By attaching the variables to the controller you are giving the templates a shared scope of visibility.

Comment: Ok so how would I `reassign` these variables using the foreach example above? I tried using `$$` but that did not work as planned.

Comment: you dont need to. just use $this->get() inside of the template.

Comment: if you really do want to pull them out, try extract()

Comment: May I point out that you should try explaining the steps to create what I did. By creating a set and get function, accessing it through the template function with extract. then we can use it. It may help others when coming to this.

Comment: You don't need a get() method. Just put them in $this directly like I suggested, or in an array. I've updated the answer. Please mark as a solution if this worked for you. Thanks.